# PHP multiplicar hora por um valor inteiro?

Tags: php

Como faço para multiplicar horas no `PHP`?

**Exemplo :**

```
$time = "0:01:00";
$mult = "5";

echo $time*$mult;
```

O retorno foi zero, porque não retornou `00:05:00`?

Comment: Não seria melhor trabalhar em uma unidade (minutos) e depois converter os resultados?

Comment: converter e depois converter... então mais fácil fazer pelo select do mysql?

Comment: Só faltou explicar o que é esse $time. Um intervalo de tempo (um minuto) ou um hórario (zero hora e um minuto)?

Comment: esse time seria um tempo de uma tarefa, quanto tempo um funcionário leva para fazer uma determinada tarefa, então tem tarefas que é alguns minutos, outras levam dias e outras podem chegar a semanas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> O retorno foi zero, porque não retornou 0:05:00?

O retorno foi zero pois você está tentando multiplicar `strings`, e a conversão do `PHP` interpretará apenas o primeiro dígito `0` da sua hora, tornando `"0:01:00"` em `0`, com isso você está fazendo `0` * `5` = `0`.

> Como faço para multiplicar horas no php?

Se quer, como informou nos comentários, multiplicar o valor total por algum multiplicador, trabalhe com `timestamp` através da função [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) e para formatar a hora, utilize [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
$time = "0:01:00";
$mult = "5";

var_dump(date("H:i:s", strtotime("00:01:00") * $mult));
var_dump(date("H:i:s", strtotime("01:07:37") * $mult));
```

O resultado será:

```
string(8) "00:05:00"
string(8) "05:38:05"
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](http://ideone.com/xvv6ZN).

@edit

> como fazer isso retornar 1 dia e 1:00:00 ?

Se precisa dessa contagem, pode fazer utilizando o `timestamp` a partir do dia inicial dele:

```
$time ='01:00:00';
$mult = 5;

$calculated = strtotime("1970-01-01 $time") * $mult;
$date = date("d H:i:s", $calculated);

$datePart = explode(" ", $date);

printf("%s dia(s) %s", $datePart[0]-1, $datePart[1]);
```

Resultará em:

```
0 dia(s) 05:00:00
1 dia(s) 01:00:00
```

Comment: Nossa obrigado pela resposta, mas tem um problema se a hora passar de 24:00:00 ele vai retornar a diferença das horas, exemplo $mult= "25" var_dump(date("H:i:s", strtotime("01:00:00") * $mult));, retornou 01:00:00

Comment: Isso seria minha proxima duvida rsss, como fazer isso retornar 1 dia e 1:00:00 ?

Comment: @Junior editei e acrescentei outra maneira, é isso?

Answer (score 7):

Você precisa utilizar a classe `DateTime`, onde nela há o método `modify` para que você possa modificar o seu `date` de acordo com a sua necessidade.

```
$time="0:01:00";
$mult="5";
$datetime=DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s',$time,new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
$datetime->modify('+' . $mult . ' minutes');
echo $datetime->format('H:i:s');
```

**EDIT**: Neste caso então, você pode pegar a quantia de minutos e multiplicar pelo valor desejado, assim:

```
$time="00:01:00";
$mult=5;
$datetime=DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s',$time,new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
$minute=$datetime->format('i');
$datetime->modify('+' . ($minute * $mult) . ' minutes');
$datetime->modify('-' . $minute  . ' minutes');
echo $datetime->format('H:i:s');
```

Além disso, coloquei para utilizar a hora em 24 e no `TimeZone` de São Paulo

Comment: Nesse caso você está somando 5 minutos, e não multiplicando as horas. Mas acredito que seja exatamente isso que o autor quer fazer.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mas gostaria de multiplicar, porque é esse tempo sendo repetido como no exemplo 5 vezes, exemplo se o tempo for 01:07:37 sendo repetido por 5 vezes o resultado é de 05:38:05. Obrigado

Comment: Realizei uma alteração na resposta, fiz alguns testes e não tive nenhum problema. Verifique se ele resolve o teu problema.

Comment: Não entendi, porque para 01:07:37 no ideone dá 01:35:37  veja https://ideone.com/ifOnTt. A pergunta é multiplicar horas e não somente os minutos.